# Multi-Dimensional Array within Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Please go through this javascript object:

```
var obj = [{
  id: "A",
  children: [{
    id: "B",
    children: [{
      id: "C",
      children: [{
        id: "D",
        children: [{
          id: "E",
          children: [{
            id: "F"
          }]
        }]
      }, {
        id: "G",
        children: {
          id: "H"
        }
      }]
    }, {
      id: "I"
    }]
  }, {
    id: "J",
    children: [{
      id: "K"
    }]
  }]
}, {
  id: "L"
}, {
  id: "M",
  children: {
    id: "N",
    children: [{
      id: "O"
    }]
  }
}, {
  id: "P"
}];
```

How to write JavaScript code to recursively parse it and print all the IDs in console so that the output looks like:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O
P
```

This is how far I could reach. I couldn't think of any logic after that.

```
for ( i=0 ; i < obj.length ; i++ ){
         var objId = obj[i];
         for( j=i; j<1 ; j++){
             console.log(obj[j].id);
             console.log(obj[j].children[j].id);
         }
     }
```

I don't understand what logic should be applied here. Do help.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: You need to traverse the object in a certain order to get the desired outcome.  Look into traversal strategies and pick the appropriate one.

Comment: you should use a recursive function. The principle : the function test if object contains a children to call itself on the children ;)

Comment: ofcourse.

 for ( i=0 ; i < obj.length ; i++ ){
      var objId = obj[i];
   for( j=i; j<1 ; j++){
       console.log(obj[j].id);
    console.log(obj[j].children[j].id);
   }
  }

This is how far I reached,

Answer (score 5):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach with a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) algorithm.

Edit: Extended for children as object.

```js
var data = [{ id: "A", children: [{ id: "B", children: [{ id: "C", children: [{ id: "D", children: [{ id: "E", children: [{ id: "F" }] }] }, { id: "G", children: { id: "H" } }] }, { id: "I" }] }, { id: "J", children: [{ id: "K" }] }] }, { id: "L" }, { id: "M", children: { id: "N", children: [{ id: "O" }] } }, { id: "P" }];

data.forEach(function iter(a) {
    console.log(a.id);
    if (Array.isArray(a.children)) {
        a.children.forEach(iter);
        return;
    }
    if (a.children && typeof a.children === 'object') { // omit this part
        iter(a.children);                               // if children is
    }                                                   // always an array
});
```

This version collects all necessary data and returns it in an array.

```js
var data = [{ id: "A", children: [{ id: "B", children: [{ id: "C", children: [{ id: "D", children: [{ id: "E", children: [{ id: "F" }] }] }, { id: "G", children: { id: "H" } }] }, { id: "I" }] }, { id: "J", children: [{ id: "K" }] }] }, { id: "L" }, { id: "M", children: { id: "N", children: [{ id: "O" }] } }, { id: "P" }],
    result = data.reduce(function iter(r, o) {
        r.push(o.id);
        if (Array.isArray(o.children)) {
            return o.children.reduce(iter, r);
        }
        if (o.children && typeof o.children === 'object') { // omit this part
            return iter(r, o.children);                     // if children is
        }                                                   // always an array
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Are you fine Nina ?   It's the first time you use forEach. I thaught you were a princess of map reduce

Comment: The requirements are all about side-effects.  Hard to use `map` when it's about side-effects!

Comment: @NinaScholz as always nice answer Nina +1. I am missing the `H` in the console log though. What if `children` is an `Object` and not an `Array`, or am i missing something here ? Ohh, and the `N` as well.

Comment: Have to ask the OP if this is intentional or accidental.  A horrible data structure if intentional!

Comment: @DavidDomain, now with `H` and `N`.

Comment: @NinaScholz great  :)

Comment: It would be better design to return an array of the ids, rather than consoling them out one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below ES6 function. Note that at two places you did not define `children` as an array, which I assume is a mistake. If it is indented, I would strongly advise to reconsider, and make it consistent throughout.

```js
function getIds(data) {
    return data.reduce((acc, el) => acc.concat(el.id, getIds(el.children || [])), [])
}

var obj = [{
  id: "A",
  children: [{
    id: "B",
    children: [{
      id: "C",
      children: [{
        id: "D",
        children: [{
          id: "E",
          children: [{
            id: "F"
          }]
        }]
      }, {
        id: "G",
        children: [{
          id: "H"
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      id: "I"
    }]
  }, {
    id: "J",
    children: [{
      id: "K"
    }]
  }]
}, {
  id: "L"
}, {
  id: "M",
  children: [{
    id: "N",
    children: [{
      id: "O"
    }]
  }]
}, {
  id: "P"
}];

console.log(getIds(obj).join('\n'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Yes, how far I am from being JS ninja. Thank's master

Comment: You've modified the input so that `children` is always an array (which is definitely a better data design, but not what the OP specified).

Comment: I wanted to mention that, as I assumed it was an error. I will add this comment to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing looks like it is asking for a depth first solution, as the order of the ids are clearly alphabetical and they are ordered by first encountered then by depth.

As a result, every id encountered will be collected, and then the deeper ids will be examined. This can, and probably should, be done with recursion.

Here is an example.

```js
  
var obj=[{id:"A",children:[{id:"B",children:[{id:"C",children:[{id:"D",children:[{id:"E",children:[{id:"F"}]}]},{id:"G",children:{id:"H"}}]},{id:"I"}]},{id:"J",children:[{id:"K"}]}]},{id:"L"},{id:"M",children:{id:"N",children:[{id:"O"}]}},{id:"P"}];

var ids = [];//output holder
(function tree(cur){ //recursive function
 for(var i = 0; i < cur.length; i++){ //iterate current set
     ids.push(cur[i].id); //always store id
     if(cur[i].children) tree(cur[i].children); //recurse if children exist
 }
})(obj) //start from the top
    
console.log(ids);
```